# Kallen-Lehman and one particle state of electron for QED

Tags: electrons, quantum-electrodynamics

We did the Kallen-Lehman procedure in lectures for phi to the fourth theory. We also defined the wavefunction renormalisation. At the end our lecturer briefly mentioned that to carry it over to QED and for an electron, what we'd have is:

$<\Omega|\psi_a(0)|e^{-}(\vec{p},s)>=\sqrt{Z} u_a^s(\vec{p})  $

$<\Omega|\psi_a(0)|e^{+}(\vec{p},s)>=\sqrt{Z} v_a^s(\vec{p})  $

Where u and v obey the usual dirac free theory equations in momentum space

$(\gamma.p-m)u^s(\vec{p})=0 $

$(\gamma.p+m)v^s(\vec{p})=0$

Now I wasn't sure how how he was able to get the u and v in to the first two expressions? Partly, because how do we define a single electron state?
I was thinking perhaps it's just the definition of what a single electron state is? Since we know u and v satisfy the free dirac equation, why not use it to define this somewhat abstract ket vector $|e^{+/-}>$?

Just wanted to add, I would ask my lecturer but can't at the moment because of the whole covid-19 thing (the lecture with this was a while ago, but I only now thought about this question).

Answer (score 2):

I think  the form is prety much forced by Lorentz covariance. You know how the field $\psi_a(x)$  transforms under boosts and rotations; you know that the vacuum state is invariant  under these operaations, and you define $|e^-(p,s)\rangle $ by rotating and the boosting   reference states  $|e^-(p^{\{0\}}),s=\pm 1/2)\rangle$ where $ p^{\{0\}}= (m,0,0,0)$ is the 4-momentum of the electron at rest. Then $u^s_a(p,s)$ is the only thing that transforms in the same way. It's just like how we know that, given
$$
\langle {\rm vac}|\phi(0)|p> =\sqrt Z 
$$
 translation invariance forces the exponential factor in
$$
\langle {\rm vac}|\phi(x)|p> =\sqrt Z e^{ipx}.
$$

Comment: I'm still confused by how you'd distinguish the electron and positron single particle states in what you've explained? Don't $v^s(p,s)$ and $u^s(p,s)$ both transform in a way that is compatible with $\psi(x)$? 

And for the last part, I know that we have the same thing in qed (i.e $<vac|\psi(x)|e^{-}(p,s)>=\sqrt{Z}u^s(p)e^{-ip.x}$) but I fail to see how that helps with showing that we should have the u in there.

Comment: It depends on the indices on $\psi_a$. In the usual diagonal $\gamma^0= {\rm diag}(1,1,-1-1)$ basis $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ annihilate spin up and spin down electrons at rest , but not positrons at rest. Meanwhile $\psi_{3,4}$ annihilate positrons at rest. For an electron at rest $u^{+1/2}_a$ is $(1,0,0,0)^T$ and $u^{-1/2}=(0,1,0,0)^T$ so these give the right constants. Meanwhile $v=(0,0,1,0)$ or  $(0,0,0,1)$ are zero for $\psi_1$ or $\psi_2$ and don't allow electron annihilation. So it all works correctly

Comment: Ah What I said is wrong--- so is one of your equations. It must be $\langle e^+(p,s) |\psi_a|\Omega\rangle = \sqrt{Z}v_a^2(p)$ Surely? $\psi_{3,4}$ *create* positrons while $\psi_{1,2}$ *anihilate* electrons.     In each case $\psi$ reduces the charge by unity.

Comment: You may be right, I've definitely copied it correctly from my notes, but he may have written it wrong by mistake. This may seem like a stupid question but how have you arrived to the conclusion that $\psi$ creates/destroys electrons/positrons? This is in Heisenberg pic with a general potential, so we cannot simply see that the creation/annihilation operators are the FT of the field (and the number operator doesn't seem so obvious either)

Comment: Do you know how the LSZ formalism works?  The $\psi$'s *etc* are interpolating fields. The point is that they are defined to have a non-zero overlap with one-particle excitations havinng the right quantum numbers, and the amount of the overlap is $\sqrt Z$

Comment: Yes, I do, but it's also a rather big/confusing topic to me. I'm just reading over it in Shwarz and he says we can define the field at any time as $\phi(x)=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_p}}[a_p(t)e^{-ip.x}+a_p^+(t)e^{ip.x}]$ . So it seems that at any time, we can define a complete set of eigenstates that behave like ladder operators, and with them can write the field operator since they're complete? In which case, this whole thing becomes a lot easier as I can just use the usual commutation relations as for the free theory

Comment: There is no "the" field for a given particle. There can be many operators with the right quantum numbers that can couple to the one-particle excitations and so serve as interpolating fields. They will have different $Z$'s but provided they are mutually local they will all give the same $S$-matrix. This is the essential point of LSZ. "Quantum numbers" only require equal time commutators so all you need is "one time" to specify them.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help. I think I may just be best trying to read various different textbooks until I feel more confident with both topics though, I feel my misunderstanding is too great to fix via a forum at the moment